# Format both c and d drive of a laptop with windows and install ubuntu

Tags: format

I have a laptop with a c drive (hdd with windows) and a d drive (SSD). I want to format both and install ubuntu on d drive. Is this possible through the normal ubuntu installation process? If I install ubuntu on d will I be able later to format the c drive through ubuntu? I only want to have ubuntu after that and not have the laptop in dual boot mode with windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1485059/edit) to clarify: Do you wish to keep WIndows (dual-boot)? Or do you want Ubuntu to be your only operating system?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1485059/edit) to clarify: Do you wish to keep any data on these drives? Or is it okay to erase all contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can use the installer to install directly to what windows calls the d drive (your ssd), and then you should be able to format the other drive using tools in Ubuntu.

The guide and links to media are here https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

I presume you’re happy that you’ll lose your Windows installation and any data on those drives. Always worth running in a live session first to ensure your hardware will run Ubuntu ok and that you’re not left without a functioning computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I don't mind losing everything in those drives. After the format of c I just need to mount the drive c and everything will be ok after that right?

Comment: @peros9 - yes, should be. (1) note that c and d are windows labels - Ubuntu won’t call  them those; (2) if you’ve not yet started, it’s worth turning off fast start up in windows before you begin. I don’t think it’ll be a big problem as you’re reformatting anyway, but windows leaves a flag on any drive when it’s hibernated, & that can prevent normal access. Once formatted, you should be able to mount the drive in Ubuntu.